# Check User Session is null or not

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to Check Save User's Credendiatals in Session in C#? Does anyone know how can I check whether a session is empty or null in .net c# web-applications?

Comment: Did you try Session["User"] != null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if( Session["User"] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["User"].ToString()))
{
  //return to login ;
}
else
{
  // your default page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Session["User"] !=null){
     Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com",true);
}
else
{
     Response.Redirect("~/login",true);
}
```